# Why is my HashMap empty after adding a value?

Tags: kotlin, minecraft

I am writing a Minecraft plugin (Paper) in Kotlin, and am running into an issue with a HashMap I am using to store players.

I have a class named `FishMatch` which has a property `players` which is a HashMap of player UUIDs and `FishMatchPlayers` (another class I made to store information about a player). When I call `FishMatch#play(player)` it adds the given player to the HashMap with the value of a new instance of `FishMatchPlayer`. However, if I print the contents of `players` from antoher method in the class, it returns as empty.

```kotlin
class FishMatch(private val plugin: Plugin) : Listener {
    private val players: HashMap<UUID, FishMatchPlayer> = hashMapOf()
    
    fun play(player: Player) {
        players[player.uniqueId] = FishMatchPlayer(plugin, player)
        // this statement logs a hashmap containing the added player
        Messages().log(plugin, players.toString())
        player.openInventory(StartInventory().inventory)
    }
    
    @EventHandler
    fun onInventoryClick(event: InventoryClickEvent) {
        val fmPlayer = players[event.whoClicked.uniqueId]
        // this statement logs an empty hashmap
        Messages().log(plugin, players.toString())
    }
}
```

`onInventoryClick` contains some further logic which ensures `fmPlayer` should never be `null`, but somehow it still it.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code shown here, which means the problem is in how you're calling these functions. Either someone else is clearing that `players` array, or you've got two different `FishMatch` instances. Try `println(this)` in both functions to see if you're actually printing out from the *same* `FishMatch` or have actually allocated two different, unrelated ones somewhere.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo You were correct about the multiple instances, the logging shows that is where the issue lies, however I cannot seem to figure out why there are two instances. The `FishMatch` class instance is created when the plugin starts, and that same instance is used to call `.play()` and is passed to the event listener (which I have since moved into its own class `FishMatchEvents`)

Comment: You'll have to show that code as well. I can't guess at the cause from only what you've said here, unfortunately.